# Is it possible to change email on published paper?

Tags: publications, errors-erratum

My paper was published two weeks ago. I have just noticed that I have provided the wrong email. Is it possible to change the email after the paper was published?

Comment: Don't ask here, ask the publisher.

Comment: You can ask this question directly to the editor.

Comment: If it is _published_ then I do not think there is any way to change any part of your paper, your email included. Changes in published papers are generally called "Corrigendum"

Comment: If "published" mean in paper form, PsySp is right.  But if only in on-line form, when you ask the editor, he may say that the new email can be added to it.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following things in this situation. But, it depends on (1) *whether it is a journal paper or a conference paper?*, (2) *whether it is already published as offprint?*

- Politely ask the publisher about it (as it is a mistake done on your part). (credit: @Dirk)
- E-mail the editor of the journal (if journal paper) and request to publish an Erratum on your behalf. (credit: @PsySp)
- Publish an erratum on your personal web page or blog.

Comment: That said, option 4 is "don't bother", and this is highly suggested. Readers are well aware that emails provided on papers are often obsolete or sort-of wrong (authors wary of spam provide addresses they barely ever check). As long as you have a website with a correct email address, no one will get it wrong.